# Form is getting submitted twice in IE and also http method is null(not going)

Tags: internet-explorer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKjbu.png)IE network image showing multiple request to same url.

So, you can see from image that reviewpay is called twice. This is happening in IE only and not in Chrome. Also, the first time reviewpay is called the method type is not there. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: use a protocol-less uri for the form action. eg action="\\paypal.com". To debug blocked content and IE security zone restrictions first go. Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages". Save changes. Now when you press the f12 tool, the console tab will list any security errors that occurred... SEC1234. I expect the action host does not accept http requests. (double click on an item in the Networking tab).To find out which IE security zone your dev/test/production website maps to use the File>Properties menu in IE. Include code with your questions.

Answer (score 0):

For IE11, you can use :

```
event.returnValue = false;
```

to avoid an error, we check if event.preventDefault exists :

```
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);
```